# How can a suggested edit allow a single-character change?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today in the Suggested Edit review I get a particular user's suggestions continuously (around 6 to 8 edits) where they are all the title's first character change (small letter to capital letter) only.

Later I see all their edits [all actions -> suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4116678/shaddy?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and those are all the same kind of edits.

Surprisingly, this particular [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10606758) contains only one character change. How this is possible?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Suggested Edit]

Comment: When I see an user does this, I mean he always suggested some minor edits, I'll go to create a chat room and talk with him about this.

Comment: Some people try to bypass the check e.g. s/i/I <!-- something -->/ This is frowned on and they'll get into trouble if they try it often enough.

Comment: And they didn't even correct the typo in the title. Anyway, judging by the quality of the question, I believe it should be taken out and shot rather than attempt to improve it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Surprisingly this particular suggested edit contains only one
>   character of change. How this is possible?

The 6 character minimum doesn't apply to title edits, presumably as a typo in a title is more important.

So this is by design. No "tricks" or bypassing of rules required.

Comment: While no tricks of bypassing of rules were used, it is not necessarily encouraged, though, correct?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan the "this edit did not correct critical issues" from reject and edit could well be appropriate if obvious other issues missed.

Comment: He's improving people's grammar. Somebody should give him a medal.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan don't reject important but otherwise brief edits, if the post is fine, except for the issue that's being fixed.

Comment: I agree, although I don't think I've ever seen a  question that simply needed a single character changed. If I do and happen to be reviewing that suggested edit, I would certainly accept it. That said, the example in the OP was polishing a turd, IMO.